# How to add virtual environment in an existing Django rest project

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, virtualenv

I have made a Django rest project I want to add virtual environment to it

https://github.com/iamahmedshahh/djangowallet

This is the structure of my project which is pretty much the default structure when creating a project from command line.